# How can I specify weight for variable font in Golang

Tags: go, fonts, truetype, google-fonts

I've download [a ttf from Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+JP) and be using it like following. It works as expected.

```golang
//go:embed NotoSansJP-VariableFont_wght.ttf
var notoSansJPData []byte

func _() {
    notoSansJP, err := opentype.Parse(notoSansJPData)
}
```

Then, I want to use bold one but can't find how to specify it.

Comment: Variable-weight TrueType fonts are relatively new and not widely supported; they do not appear to be supported by `golang.org/x/image/font/opentype`. Grab the font file for the weight you want, and use that.

Comment: Thanks. Then I just use weighted font file. And await the feature or perhaps submit an issue.